# reactjs material ui button not worked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was trying to make a simple react weather app and it worked but not properly because before add the material-ui button it was working perfect and now it is working only if i click enter not click on the button because the material-ui `const city = e.target.elements.city.value;` this code is not working with it at all 
 here is the form component is like

```
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={props.getWeather}>
        <p>Just type the city name </p>
        <p className="check">you must spelling correctly</p>

        <TextField
          id="standard-basic"
          name="city"
          placeholder="City....."
          variant="outlined"
        />
        <Button onClick={props.getWeather} variant="contained" color="primary">
          find
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

and in the app component

```
getWeather = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const api = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`
    );
const data = await api.json();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove onClick handler from button and add type="submit", so it'll work both in case of Enter click and button click:

```
<Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
   find
</Button>
```

It's going to work only when your button is in hierarchy of `<form>` type="submit" simply submits the form.